# Find 3D coordinates of end point of a vector given the distance and the angle

Tags: c, 3d

How can I find the coordinates of P ? I've seen other posts in 2D and also in 3D but they say that I need 3 angles for 3D and some say I only need two but I dont understand which ones, I suck at math.

All See this image, I have is those two angles and the distance between B and P

[image]

Comment: Do you have co-ordinates of point B?

Answer (score 1):

To define a vector in 3D, given its length, you need 2 angles. These 3 coordinates (length + 2 angles) are named "spherical coordinates". There are 3 conventions for defining such angles. The most common one is the radius-elevation-azimuth. In this convention, expression of the cartesian coordinates of the vector, given the radius, elevation angle and azimuth angle are:

```
x = radius * sin(elevation) * cos(azimuth)
y = radius * sin(elevation) * sin(azimuth)
z = radius * cos(elevation)
```